# How can I set a property on a master page from a custom control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a master page.

I'm working on a testpage which inherits the master page.

the master page has a public property which is accessible to turn visibility on and off.

I have a set of controls which I can include into testpage.  One of these controls needs to be able to set the visibility of a masterpage control.

Normally in a page code behind I would just say;

```
this.Master.ShowItem = false;
```

I have no idea how to be able to access this property from the custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to cast the master to the correct type. Assuming the type of your master is `SiteMaster`:

```
var master = this.Page.Master as SiteMaster;
if(master != null)  // cast failed, your master is a different type
{
    master.ShowItem = false;
}
```

So the navigation is:

- [`UserControl.Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx)
- [`Page.Master`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx)
- type cast

Comment: More downvotes without a comment please. Have i overlooked something obvious?

Comment: i haven't downvoted anybody, thanks I'll try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

(sry due to my reputation I cant make comments, so as an answer)

Hint: Make sure that the Property you want to access in the master page is set to public.

Heeding this the solution of Tim Schmelter works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can set a property of master page directly.
But you can find the control of the master page and made them visible/invisible from conternt page like this:

```
((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("IdOfTYurControl")).Visible = false;
```

Comment: Your technique for accessing the master page could work, but stating that you can't set a property is definitely incorrect.

Comment: But even if it works, you don't know if it'll still work tomorrow when someone is going to correct the ID-typo. Relying on ID's on something that is accessible from everywhere  it's not so good. Also, on this way you expose the complete control, what if someone decides to change the `Label` to a `TextBox` or so? You have no control. Most important, it's not self-explaining. A property is strongly typed, has compile time safety, intellisense support and maybe even documentation.